# How do I start smbclient from a script in Linux?

Tags: shell-script, csh

I want to be able to quickly start smbclient to a specific directory without typing or copying it to the shell command line, but just sticking it in a script doesn't seem to work...

```
#!/bin/csh
smbclient -W blah -U name -D "really long directory location" server/service
```

I've made it executable, but when I run it via ./smbcommand it does nothing. Normally if I execute it from the command line, it asks for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Try `csh -x ./smbcommand` - at least you will see if the shell executes your script or not.